# Compile error; user defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I'm now to Excel VBA and recently got this error when trying to run a Macro (Compile error; user defined type not defined).  The highlighted error (in bold) is as follow:

```
Dim xmlToImport AS MSXML.2.DOMDocument
Set xmlToImport = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
```

Not sure why I've been getting this recently, but any assistance would be helpful.  I'm also very new to VBA so bear with me. :)  Thanks!!

Comment: You need to enable the reference for Microsoft XML `Extra -> Reference -> Check Microsoft XML`. And then ist should be `Dim xmlToImport AS MSXML2.DOMDocument` (there is no dot before the 2).

Comment: I didn't mean to put the dot before the 2, that was my mistake.  Looking through the available References and seeing what I need to check off..

Comment: do I check "Microsoft XML, v6.0"?

Comment: wait... i add the Microsoft XML, v3.0 and I think that fixed it.  Thanks, MG92!!!